# Combined Summary in Visual Studio Lightswitch HTML Client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm having issue with the summary property in a Visual Studio Lightswitch HTML Client application.

I have a table of Users which has properties FirstName and LastName. I created a calculated property called FullName which concatenates the two automatically, yet it doesn't look like I can select a calcuated property as the summary property from the HTMLClient perspective.

I've been able to get around this in some places by replacing reference to the User summary in screens with labels for both FirstName and LastName.

[image]

However, this does not work for a details picker. I can add both the FirstName and LastName fields to a User details picker.

[image]

Both properties will show up when selecting a User from the picker.

[image]

Yet once selected only the summary is displayed in the control. So in this case only the FirstName is shown.

[image]

Not to mention trying to track down everywhere my app is showing the User summary is a hassle. I'd much prefer the summary work in most cases, and only have to add additional properties when I know I need to show more information.

The current hack/workaround I came up with is to create a real (not calculated) FullName property in the Users table which can be assigned as the summary. Then I added code to set this property when `Users_Created()` or `Users_Updated()` is called. This works but it created duplicate information in the database and adds logic to the back-end which should probably only be of concern the the front end.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: You could create a view and add it to your DataSource and use it everywhere you require a details picker.

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution for this? I'm currently looking for the exact same thing.